# Mac 10.6.8 - Homebrew - Xcode not installed

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

I just started using Homebrew, but I am running into trouble right away.

The problem is that `brew doctor` keeps telling me 'Xcode not installed'.

I have seen a similar question (15891818) on this topic, but there was just a partial solution for Node.js

I first had Xcode 3.1 installed, and when I ran brew doctor it correctly informed me my Xcode was an old version, and told me to upgrade to 3.2.6. So I downloaded Xcode 3.2.1 from the apple site, after that I did a Software Update and upgraded to 3.2.6.

After this, Homebrew just doesn't find the Xcode installation at all. (I even restarted my computer)

I am on OS 10.6.8.

any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: 10.6.8 - I put it in the title of my question - will add it to the body as well

Comment: Why are you still using XCode 3.x now? Update to a newer version should solve the problem.

Comment: Because Homebrew explicitely told me to use 3.2.6. I am not even sure if xcode 4 runs on 10.6.8

Comment: ok, this was my first SO question, I don't know what the procedure is, but we might as well close this one. The background of my question was that I want to use PyTables, but somehow my Python 2.7 installation was a bit funky, and pip and easy_install were not working. So I hoped to fix this installation with Homebrew. Now I fixed it manually, and I used pip to install PyTables successfully. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

homebrew needs gcc, which i got from here without having to install xcode https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Comment: ok, thank you. Currently I am using pip, which works fine, so I am  not touching homebrew for the time being.